# django-admin-tools 3 column layout not working

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm using django-admin-tools 0.4.
Following the docs [here](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-admin-tools/en/latest/dashboard.html) so that I can get a 3 column layout.

I have managed to get the page to space correctly for 3 columns but the Modules can't move over to the 3rd column.

I can only drag from the left column to the middle but not right.

**How can I get the modules to move between the 3 columns?**

[My dashboard.py can be viewed here.](http://pastebin.com/SPdQ6fKg)
I've attached a screenshot to show what result I have.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue was that **admin_tools_dashboard_preferences** needs to be truncated(almost for every change being made to the dashboard.)

Also the first snippet of code on the [documentation page](http://django-admin-tools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dashboard.html#dashboard) didn't even work for me. I took snippets from other parts of the docs and they seemed to work no problems.
In the end my example dashboard looks something like this.
Remember to truncate your preferences.

```
class MyDashboard(Dashboard):

    columns = 3

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Dashboard.__init__(self, **kwargs)

        # will only list the django.contrib.auth models
        self.children += [
            modules.ModelList('Authentication', ['django.contrib.auth.*',])
        ]

        self.children.append(modules.Group(
            title="My group",
            display="tabs",
            children=[
                modules.AppList(
                    title='Administration',
                    models=('django.contrib.*',)
                ),
                modules.AppList(
                    title='Applications',
                    exclude=('django.contrib.*',)
                )
            ]
        ))
        self.children.append(modules.LinkList(
            layout='inline',
            children=(
                {
                    'title': 'Python website',
                    'url': 'http://www.python.org',
                    'external': True,
                    'description': 'Python programming language rocks !',
                },
                ['Django website', 'http://www.djangoproject.com', True],
                ['Some internal link', '/some/internal/link/'],
            )
        ))
```